# Test for convergence for $f(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there any known theorem or result that gives necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the convergence of the following serie:

$$\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^nf(n)$$

Comment: This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that [I did not even know the name of the test]. Very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A necessary condition** is $f(n) \to 0$.

The Alternating series test is a **sufficient condition**.

**Another sufficient condition** is the convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0} |f(n)|$. Note that this is often helpful since, this is a positive series, thus in many situations you can use tests which are not available for the original series.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one that is sufficient. If $f(n)\downarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$, the series must converge. This is the alternating series test of basic Calculus.

Comment: You also need $f(n)\geq0$; the sum certainly does not converge if $f(n)=(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: The downarrow says, "$f(n)$ decrease to zero."

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not familiar with that notation.

Answer (score 1):

If lim n-> inf f(n)=0, and f(n+1) < f(n), the alternating series converges.  This test doesn't take the "alternator" (-1)^n into account.